# TFS - check in to two different TFS servers

Tags: tfs, checkin

We have a local TFS server and our client has their own TFS server. We need to check in code to both servers. Is there a simple way to switch between TFS instances without having to unbdind and delete all vss* related files and then rebind to the other TFS server?  Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can't check-in code to multiple servers for many reasons. One reasons is the pending change. Once you check them in, they are not pending changes anymore. Another reason is, if you are talking about TFS 2010 or lower, so you are talking about Server Workspace, you have to be connected to the server, not like the new local workspace that introduced in TFS 11 Beta. Anyway my advice to you: just use TFS Integration Tool to integrate between the two servers.

http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/